# How do I use Repl.it's database?

Tags: javascript, database, discord, discord.js, replit

I need my bot to save user violations to a database when a user uses a command. For example, when `#violate @user red light pass` is used, the bot should save the red light pass to the database for the mentioned user. I'm using [Repl.it's database](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@replit/database) and this is my code:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("#violations")) {
    let violation = await db.get(`wallet_${message.author.id}`)

    if (violation === null) violation = "you dont have any tickets"

    let pembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.author.username} violations`)
      .setDescription(`المخالفات المرورية : ${violation}`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setFooter("L.S.P.D")
    message.channel.send(pembed)
  }

  if (message.channel.id === '844933512514633768') {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    console.log(args);

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'red light pass') {
      const member = message.mentions.members.first(); // 
      let light = "red lightpass"
      await db.set(`wallet_${memeber}`, light)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in `` `wallet_${memeber}` ``, `memeber` is not defined. You probably intended to use `` `wallet_${member}` ``.

I believe the issue is you're using the key `` `wallet_${message.author.id}` `` (e.g. `'wallet_12345'`) to get the violation/ticket, but then `` `wallet_${member}` `` (e.g. `'wallet_<@12345>'`) (e.g. `'wallet`) to set the violation. Interpolating a `GuildMember` in a string calls its [`toString`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=toString) method, which creates a string of the *mention* of the member, not the id.

Also, it's [good practice to use `===` instead of `==`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq)  as `==` casts the items being compared so things like `3 == '03'` and `[] == false` are `true`.

The final code should like this:

```js
if (command === "red light pass") {
  const member = message.mentions.members.first();
  const light = "red lightpass";
  // Note how I've changed this to member.id (which is just a shortcut for
  // member.user.id) from memeber
  await db.set(`wallet_${member.id}`, light);
}
```